# FFMPEG - remove sharp signal spikes from audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, filtering

[image]Do you know ffmpeg audio filter settings to remove sharp signal spikes?
I already tried some ffmpeg filters (adeclip etc.) but nothing worked.
I have spikes on one of my microphone audio channels, screenshot attached..

Comment: I have never seen such an audio signal coming from a mic ... to me its due to a faulty mic especially if both channels were recorded using two different microphones (even using a stereo mic) in same proximity where other channel has no indication of those spikes

Comment: Yes, it is faulty mic. on my 2yr old cellphone Xiaomi mi8 lite. It records stereo.. and only right channel generates few such spikes around 5second of recording. The rest of recording is ok..
Those spikes look like some "capacitor discharging". I'm buying new cell phone soon.. However I want to fix those dozens videos I took over those 2 years..

Comment: easiest route would be to simply make the audio mono using the good channel or if stereo is needed replace bad channel by duplicating over good channel ... are these mp4 files ?